# AWS API Gateway CORS Ajax Request Returning Error

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use API Gateway as my server for a small database project, and I'm using Ajax to upload data to the server. I know I need to enable CORS to allow me to have cross-domain requests, and I've tried over and over multiple different methods of enabling CORS that I've found online, with no luck. No matter what I do, I seem to get the same error callback: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Here is the code I am using in the ajax request (for obvious reasons I omitted the URL of the API):

```
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: API_URL,
          data: data,
          crossDomain: true,
          dataType: "text",
          contentType: 'text/plain',
          success: (data, status, xhr) => {
            alert("Success");
          },
          error: (e) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
          }
        });
```

CORS is in fact enabled in my API, I can confirm this by checking the integration response for my OPTIONS method (there's only one resource and the only methods that exist for it are POST and OPTIONS). Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated, trying to make this work has been very frustrating.

Comment: Show your CORS policy.

Comment: You may need to show from which you url you are trying to access and what is your response headers too. That will help to determine the problem.

Comment: Side note: `crossDomain: true` doesn't help here. All it does is simulate a cross-domain request in a situation where in reality there isn't one. It's really only any use for testing. Read the docs for it in the jQuery ajax page.

Comment: Anyway as others have said, since CORS policy is determined server-side, there's nothing in the code you've posted which gives any clue as to why you've got a problem. Check in your browser's console for errors, and also in your network tab to see what headers you get back from the initial OPTIONS request, in case the headers are wrong. And show how you set up CORS in the server.

Comment: Could you please update the question with what your `POST` method is integrating with?  HTTP proxy?  Lambda?  Other?